# AccesControl filter for standalone actions

Tags: php, yii2

I'm using AccessControl with matchCallback like this

```
        'access' => [
        'class' => \yii\filters\AccessControl::className(),
            'rules' => [
                [
                    'allow' => true,
                    'roles' => ['@'],
                    'matchCallback' => function ($rule, $action) {
                        $action = yii::$app->controller->action->id;
                        $controller = yii::$app->controller->id;
                        $route = "$controller/$action";
                        if (Yii::$app->user->can($route)) {
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                ]
        ]
    ]
```

All my permissions for RBAC are created like this - controller/action and this works for inline actions, but doesn't work for standalone actions like this:

```
 public function actions()
    {
        return [
            'cbaccept' => [
                'class' => ToggleAction::className(),
                'modelClass' => 'app\models\base\Drawing',
                'attribute'=>'cbaccepted',
            ],
```

How to check for standalone action in `matchCallback` ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it's not working for standalone actions? It should.

And your callback can be simpler:

```
'matchCallback' => function ($rule, $action) {
    $route = $action->controller->id . '/' . $action->id;
    return Yii::$app->user->can($route);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Actually found my mistake. I've accidentally assigned a role along with permissions, so it works.